# Css: Position element by it's bottom relative to it's container's top

Tags: html, css, position

I have an `div` element with variable height which I need to be positioned by it's `bottom` relative to the containers top.

This must be done without changing the html.

e.g.

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Some Text<br/>more...</h1>
</div>
```

`h1`'s bottom should be 100px below `#container`'s top.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

So by Request what I did (or didn't) tried:

- Searching with Google for `css bottom top position relative` but that's not the best search terms in the world...
- Normally I would put a container around `h1` and give it a height of 100px but then I would need to change the html and that I can't
- using `bottom: somevalue` but that positions the element's *bottom* relative to the container's bottom.
- slain some vampires

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: I simply don't know how to do it. `bottom: somevalue` positions something's bottom relative to containers bottom. So I need some neat trick I don't know about. Really can't show you anything.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking questions. I downvoted because, as the downvote button says, "This question does not show any research effort". You mentioned that you tried "bottom: somevalue". You might want to include that in your post and explain/show how that did not work for you.

Comment: This is plain stupid. I know what `bottom` does and don't need no research to know that this is *not* what I need. I could write that I would use an container around `h1` with an height of `100px` and position `h1` on that's bottom but that's not what I need either. (and I wrote that in my question) I could tell you that `bottom top position relative` are not the best keywords to search for. (I tried) But what's the point? Just to prove you something? Come on!

Comment: Yes. Exactly. There are many [help vampires](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) on the internet. You don't seem to be one, but it takes the same amount of time to rant as it does to show what you've tried. I'm sorry if you don't like SO procedures. Realistically, one downvote is fairly meaningless and I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could make use of `transform: translateY(-100%)`, to make the bottom of the element relative when you apply `margin-top: 100px` to `h1`.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: tan;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container h1 {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: papayawhip
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Some Text<br/>more...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It's clear the person asking is unaware of advance techniques and what you  propose is overkill. margin/padding top of 100px would be enough.

Comment: @Bart - So how do you think `margin` would work if the `height` of `h1` is unknown?

Comment: fair enough. I apologize.

Comment: @Bart - No worries. :)

Comment: Brilliant! I'm already using transform/translate for animations and stuff but using it to change the reference point is something I completely missed. It will go straight into my library! (It nearly feels like *the missing piece* :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thankyou! this helped me a lot for taking autocomplete search results and displaying them upwards instead of down when theyre out of the viewport

Answer (score 6):

Depending on browser support requirements:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#container h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/jessekernaghan/pen/jEBoeZ)

Comment: I'm looking forward to using this stuff (in the not so distant future I hope) ;)

Comment: @Scheintod the browser support is actually pretty good ( minus IE8 and opera mini ) http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc 
I've started using it in most projects unless the demographic dictates otherwise ( government/large corporation work )

Comment: It's e-commerce here. I'm already using stuff like flex-layout. But only where it gracefully degrades. And in this case it wouldn't. But thanks for the hint. I will register this somewhere in my brain in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

This code is not affecting html at all. I added css for id-container. 
An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. You can change it to fixed it you wants to.

Height of the container, help you to calculate spacing from bottom.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. How does this solve the issue?

Comment: What I mean is, how does this achieve "h1's bottom should be 100px below #container's top"?

Answer (score 0):

Only way through it is to add a height to the h1 unless you want to go with calc which isn't supported yet by some browsers. Then set your top margin to be top: 100px - h1's height. Hope this works

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Some Text<br/>more...</h1>
</div>

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container h1 {
  background: #444;
  position:relative;
  height:80px;
  top:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms889w57/

Comment: That puts the *top* of the `<h1>` 100px below the top of `#container` (plus the margin on the `<h1>`). The OP requests: "h1's *bottom* should be 100px below #container's top." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @showdev Misunderstood the question, will edit my post with a correct answer in 5min

Comment: Fixing the height is out of question in this case. (h1 has a background and is positioned over an image). But thanks for your answer nevertheless.